# MongoDB - NodeJs - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get this error when saving the schema below in MongoDB/NodeJs (with Mongoose):
  **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.**

This occurs when I add details in my schema in the Array:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Attribute = new mongoose.Schema({
  context: String,
  format: String,
  measurand: String,
  location: String,
  unit: String
});

const Value = new mongoose.Schema({
  value: Number,
  attributes: Attribute
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('MeterValue',{
  chargeBoxID: {type: String, ref: 'ChargingStation'},
  connectorId: Number,
  transactionId: Number,
  timestamp: Date,
  values: [Value]
});
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!
Serge.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define an extra schema for the model in the array.

Something like:

```js
const AddressSchema mongoose.Schema({
   address1: { type: String },
   address2: { type: String },
});

...

module.exports = mongoose.model('Person',{
  _id: String,
  name: String,
  address: [ AddressSchema ],
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I had also tried this without success :(

Comment: I updated the message so you can check with my real data ;-)

Comment: I see. First thing are you sure this is working `{type: String, ref: 'ChargingStation'}` i just saw that with an object id reference. Then its not clear if `attributes` means just one `Attribute` schema or is it also an array?

Comment: Yes, I changed the _id of the Charging Station to a String as its name is unique, easier then to identify it in other schemas. It's just one attribute; I agree it's confusing with the name 'attributes'.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`
This occurred when I was trying to save the list of an object inside a field. What I figured out was you should not pass the list as it is.

I had a model called `Order` that accepts List of `Items`.
Break down the whole process into two steps:

1. Simply create your `Order` model without the lists
2. use `.findByIdAndUpdate`

```
    const order = await OrderModel.create({
                  status: "initiated",
                  createdAt: new Date(),
                });

    await OrderModel.findByIdAndUpdate(order, {
              $push: {
                items: cartItems,
              },
            });
```

Here items is the field inside the model that accepts a list of items.
this way, you won't get the issue of Maximum Stack size exceeded. Hope it helps.